# event.x seems to not work

Tags: lua, coronasdk

I have this scene, I want when the earth collide with the blackhole an explosion sprite to be played.

[image]

So I wrote this:

```
local function onCollision( event )
    if ( event.phase == "began" ) then   
        if(event.object1.name =="blackholeSprite" or event.object2.name =="blackholeSprite") then
            explosionSprite.x=event.x
            explosionSprite.y=event.y
        explosionSprite:play()
        timer.performWithDelay( 1500, gameOver )        
        end 
    end

end
```

The problem is that the explosion does not occur where the ball and the blackhole collide `event.x` and `event.y` . As you can see from the screenshot the explosion take place in the top-left corner. Any idea why this happens?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe it is because of what is reported in the [docs](http://docs.coronalabs.com/api/event/collision/index.html) under "gotchas" for collision events.

> ### Gotchas
>
> The x and y position can be influenced by `physics.getAverageCollisionPositions()` and `physics.setReportCollisionsInContentCoordinates()`.
>
> #### Event position
>
> During the "ended" phase (See the Collision Detection Guide), the X and Y positions are always zero. This is a Box2D limitation.
>
> Also, when a collision involves a circle, and if the collision result is returned in local-space (see `physics.setReportCollisionsInContentCoordinates()`, then the local-space position of the collision is always 0,0. This is a Box2D limitation.

To solve your issue you could try to get the coordinates from (one of) the objects themselves, instead of getting them from the event.